# Arm templates copy loop conditionally check index

Tags: azure, devops, azure-rm-template

Is there option copy iteration check conditionally in ARM templates? Example if copy index is zero set another value?

My ARM Code:

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
      "location": {
        "type": "string",
        "defaultValue": "[resourceGroup().location]"
      },
      "storageAccountName": {
        "type": "string"
      },
      "mediaServicesAccountName": {
        "type": "string"
      }
    },
    "functions": [],
    "resources": [
      {
        "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
        "apiVersion": "2021-01-01",
        "name": "[concat('storage', copyIndex(), uniqueString(resourceGroup().id))]",
        "location": "[parameters('location')]",
        "sku": {
          "name": "Standard_LRS"
        },
        "kind": "StorageV2",
        "copy": {
            "name": "storagecopy",
            "count": 3
        }
      },
      {
      "type": "Microsoft.Media/mediaservices",
      "apiVersion": "2020-05-01",
      "name": "[parameters('mediaServicesAccountName')]",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "properties": {
        "storageAccounts": [
          {
            "type": "Primary", # Primary if copyIndex is zero otherwise Secondary
            "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', concat('storage', copyIndex(), uniqueString(resourceGroup().id)))]"
          }
        ]
      },
      "identity": {
        "type": "SystemAssigned"
      },
      "dependsOn": ["storagecopy"]
    }
    ],
    "metadata": {
      "_generator": {
        "name": "bicep",
        "version": "0.3.126.58533",
        "templateHash": "2006367938138350540"
      }
    }
  }
```

In above code I am creating 3 storage accounts and after that I am creating azure media service, I need to map storage accounts to azure media service dynamically. Under properties, I need to use copy loop and set Primary if index is zero else Secondary for defined number of storages.

Below Block implementation is required for copy loop condition:

```
"storageAccounts": [
              {
                "type": "Primary", # Primary if copyIndex is zero otherwise Secondary
                "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', concat('storage', copyIndex(), uniqueString(resourceGroup().id)))]"
              }
            ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a separate loop over `storageAccounts` property:

```json
 {
      "type": "Microsoft.Media/mediaservices",
      "apiVersion": "2020-05-01",
      ...
      "properties": {
        "copy": [
          {
            "name": "storageAccounts",
            "count": "3",
            "input": {
              "type": "[if(equals(copyIndex('storageAccounts'), 0), 'Primary', 'Secondary']", # Primary if copyIndex is zero otherwise Secondary
              "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', concat('storage', copyIndex('storageAccounts'), uniqueString(resourceGroup().id)))]"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
```

See more information here: [Property iteration in ARM templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/copy-properties)